# When making an array of objects, when I alter the properties of one, they all change

Tags: java, arrays, swing

So I have a class, called Hero:

```
public class Hero {
public static int x;
public static int y;

Hero() {
    x=0;
    y=0;
}

Hero(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Hero(Hero h) {
    this(h.x, h.y);
}
```

}

I made an array of Heros. However, when I change hero[0], hero[1] and all the others change as well. Also, when I make another hero, like this:

```
Hero guy = new Hero();
```

and change his x like this:

```
guy.x = 4;
```

suddenly all Hero objects I have created have an x value of 4.

Another example within the same project:

```
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
public class bonusItem extends JMenuItem{
public static int X;
public static int Y;

bonusItem(String s, int x, int y) {
    super(s);
    X=x;
    Y=y;
}

public void setCols(int cols) {
    X = cols;
}

public void setRows(int rows) {
    Y = rows;
}

public int getCols() {
    return X;
}

public int getRows() {
    return Y;
}
```

}

If I do this (after making the array, of course):

```
    bonus[1].setRows(9);
    bonus[1].setCols(9);
    bonus[0].setRows(8);
    bonus[0].setCols(8);

    for(int i=0; i<bonusCount; i++) 
                System.out.println("Bonus " + i + " has " + 
                    bonus[i].getRows() + " rows and "
                         + bonus[i].getCols() + " columns.");
```

The output is:
    Bonus 0 has 8 rows and 8 columns.
    Bonus 1 has 8 rows and 8 columns.

I'd really just like to have an array of discrete objects, rather than whatever's going on here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to.  You need to understand what `static` means.

Comment: To expand on Hanky Panky's answer, the point of `static` is to produce the exact behavior that you observed-- sometimes, that's exactly what you want!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is a classic explanation of the `static` phenomena.

```
public static int x;
public static int y;
```

Using `static` how do you even expect that you can have different values for different objects?

`static` members are for the class itself, they are not tied to any single object. Hence a `static` 
will keep the same value even if you have hundreds of objects.

From [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
>   This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
>   static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
>   variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any
>   object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
>   in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
>   class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without
>   creating an instance of the class.

You should be declaring them like

```
private int x; // or public like you did
private int y;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been chasing that forever.